# How to connect two virbr0 on two different KVM hosts?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

I have one KVM host with VM's inside which using virbr0 virtual network(10.0.0.0/24). Now i got new KVM host machine for new VM's which must use ip's from same network and to be able to communicate with VM's on first KVM host. Is it possible to connect this two KVM hosts, so VM's can communicate on same network?

Comment: so, what have you tried so far to achieve that? Yes, it's possible to do.

Comment: nothing, googled it without any luck so far.

Comment: maybe you could just try doing it ;-)

Comment: @natxoasenjo what's the point of commenting if it's not going to be helpful? This is not an easy task, in fact, it's nearly impossible with conventional methods. The virbr0 is a private network that allows 10.0.0.0/24 access Internet/external network via NAT, however, nothing from outside can access that guest. (like nothing can connect to your private IP address on your Wifi from Internet without extra steps to make that possible)

Comment: @Maziyar, how do you know virbr0 is private and natted? The default virbr0 if I remember correctly is 192.168.122.0/24 in ubuntu too, but OP indicates another one. So I do think my  comments are necessary to know what OP has done in order to help successfully. Besides, affirming that something is impossible when plenty of people have it working, is quite a statement.

Comment: @natxoasenjo I mean it's literally in the OP's post: `virbr0 virtual network(10.0.0.0/24)` that tells me the setup is that all the guests on that KVM host will have a private IP that will use the NAT to access outside but not the other way around. The other KVM host probably has the same situation. In fact, this is the case that it's really hard to make the two KVM hosts have their guests communicate via two private networks. (the other way around that it's just a bridge on the LAN doesn't need a question) - I would be glad to see an answer to this exact situation.

Comment: @Maziyar, that does not mean it is natted though. You can have private addresses that are not natted internally. This is a common scenario in business scenarios where kvm is used. This is quite off topic now, if you have a specific question, open your own one.

Comment: @natxoasenjo I don't have any questions, just an honest opinion, comments like the one you left discourse users to ask any questions just because they look, newbie. If it's simple to you or very obvious, please don't say that. You can just answer it or leave a link to an already answered similar question(s). Best of luck.

Comment: This is a site for professionals. I asked another professional what had been done. Still waiting for the answer. You keep trying to catch me in a mistake to no avail, it would be nice if you stopped doing that.